# Is it possible to access other files in a Helper file in Magento TAF?

Tags: php, magento, phpunit

I am trying to create an instance of another class in a Helper class of a module in Magento TAF. So, tried using require_once. But the file is not included in the Helper Class. So, is it possible to include any php file in a Helper class?

Comment: You can not access files from your Helper but you can make utility functions instead

Comment: Can you specify some example how is it done?

Comment: Do you need to know how to create Helpers in Magento ?

Comment: Yes. But, Magento TAF testsuite requires phpdbunit. So have to create an instance inside the Helper or some Test.php to access other file's methods.